# Convert columns in float to int using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

Good day i would like to convert `floa`t to `int`, I read some documents in `pandas` how to convert and i converted it but the problem is i have many columns to convert so I create this code but the said error is `unable to open 'util.pxd'` please help thank you

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


path = 'path file'
readAllcsv = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.csv", recursive = True)]


for f in readAllcsv:
data = pd.read_csv(f)
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
col = list(data.columns.values)
convertDatatype = { i : 'int64' for i in col if i not in ['sensor_id','time','date'] }
data = data.astype(convertDatatype)
print(data.dtypes)
```

but when i do this it works what is wrong with my code thank you

```
path = 'path file'
readAllcsv = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.csv", recursive = True)]


for f in readAllcsv:
data = pd.read_csv(f)
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)


test = {'out_others':'int32','out_tryke':'int32','out_total':'int32','in_car':'int32','in_bus':'int32','in_med_truck':'int32'}
data = data.astype(test)
print(data.dtypes)
```

Comment: good day maam sir i know the error solve

Comment: i have a column that the data type is a object so i added it on not in [ ' ' ] and i works now thank you